# Is there support for XML code hinting / completion in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext2

I am giving Sublime Text 2 a try and I was editing an XML file - that had a `DOCTYPE` declaration and a DTD  - and there seems to be no way to get code hinting / completion when editing the XML document.

I am sure its something simple I am overlooking. I cannot imagine Sublime does not have this kind of functionality, even if provided via a plugin.

Can someone shed some light on this for me?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sublime Text is first and foremost a text editor.
But, the reason for it's popularity is in large part due to it's extensibility.

Although you could use Sublime's api to create a specific plug-in to do this, Sublime has a few tools that are already helpful in editing xml files and other markup files on a bare install.

Hinting and completions in particular are very easy to add. It shouldn't take a more than few minutes to create a domain specific [sublime-completions](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/completions.html) file for your particular xml. 
You can use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> to create an xml element, in addition <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> will close any un-closed xml element.

You may also want to try the [Sublime Tag plug-in](https://github.com/SublimeText/Tag) available through [Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/community)

Lastly you could also bring this up in the [Sublime forums](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/) as a plug-in request. There are a lot of helpful folks in the plug-in community.

Comment: Regardless of the solution, it seems like a lot of effort for something that I would think would be supported 'out of the box'. Bummer...I like just about everything else. Not having this support will be a pain - I still use XML quite a bit, even if only for ColdSpring config. Would be cool if it had the ability to look at DTD and offer code completion/hinting.

Comment: I think a case can be made that a plugin should exist for whatever it is you need to do anyway. And although cool, I disagree that DTD code insight should be a standard "out of the box" feature for a svelte snippets based text editor - just as I would other language introspection, ftp, and version control. But, I completely understand that that is arguable.

Comment: I think its funny how people tout Sublime as this amazing powerful tool, yet when I ask about XML support all I have heard is 'Its just a text editor, what do you expect'. I think Sublime is a nice product, but I cannot see myself using it regularly because I _need_ to edit XML files often enough that the annoyance of having to open another editor/IDE would counteract the awesomeness of everything else. Marking your answer as accepted so the Stack Overflow Gods don't get angry with us for discussing opinions.

Comment: I think another thing that bothers me about this is that Sublime is not free/OSS. I think I would be more accepting of the 'you can make your own plugin' if I did not need to shell out $60 (US) for it.

Comment: Whenever I try out the hip tools of the bearded devs, Sublime etc, I soon hurry back to the imperfect but warm bosom of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 'tag' plugin from Sublime Package Control. It has auto tag closing, linting and other features. The github page for the project is here: https://github.com/SublimeText/Tag

You can install it using Package Control without leaving your Sublime text editor.